# Вычисление вырежения

Tags: c#

Вычислить значение выражений.
Начальными значениями переменных c и d для каждого выражения: c = 2 и d = 1.
В ответе указать: значение и тип результата, конечное значение заданных переменных.

а) `c *= ++d`

б) `c++%2 >= --d*2`

в) `(d – c > 0) || (c – d > 0) ? c : d`

Как ещё эти два выражения туда запихнуть и чтобы оно сразу все считывало

Result:

```
using System;


public class HelloWorld
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int c = 2, d = 1;
 
        
        var a = (d - c> 0) || (c - d> 0)? c: d;
Console.WriteLine($"Zna4ennya C = {c}, Zna4ennya d = {d}, Zna4ennya resultata = {a}, type resultata = {a.GetType()}");


    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? В третьем случае же int будет, ни к чему тип выводить автоматически.

Comment: _"Как ещё эти два выражения туда запихнуть и чтобы оно сразу все считывало"_ - почему два? Куда туда? Кто оно? Откуда считывало?

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что у вас консольное приложение.
Вы хотите передать в него значения и выполнить некие операции над ним, затем вывести результат в некоем определенном виде.

чтобы считать введеное значение в консоли необходимо:

1. Объявить переменые в которые будут считываться данные
2. Считать в них данные командой `Console.ReadLIne()`

При запуске программы выполнение будет остановлено до момента ввода текста.
Значение считается, но будет храниться в типе `string`  для математических операций необходимо преобразовать (привести) в тип `int`. Это можно сделать через метод `Parse()` в самом целевом типе.

Далее можно выполнять необходимые операции над значениями и выводить их в консоль через метод `Console.WriteLine()`